# CSS: fit an image into an unknown size parent

Tags: css

Here is below a simplified version of what I have.

The goal is to fit the image into its parent. In other words, the image size must not exceed the parent size. `max-width` and `max-height` don't work because the parent (`#media-insert`) don't have a known size. What is currently happening, is that the parent increases its size to fit the image.

This is really easy solve by setting the image as the background of the parent instead of inserting it into the parent. However, I don't want to do that, because I want to be able to replace the image by a video.

Also, I don't want to modify the HTML. Keep in mind that this is a simplified version, in the real world there is more going on in the layout.

Thanks

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#media-description {
  /* the description must take the minimum possible space (flex-grow: 0) to fit everything (flex-shrink: 0) */
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

#media-wrapper {
  /* the wrapper should shrink/grow to fit the remaining space */
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#media-wrapper #media-insert {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* center the image */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#media-wrapper #media-insert img {
  display: block;
  /* image must fit inside the parent (doesn't work) */
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

/***** debug *****/

main {
  border: 5px solid red;
  /* simulate phone screen */
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
}

#media-wrapper {
  border: 5px solid green;
}

#media-insert {
  border: 5px solid lightgreen;
}


#media-description {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="media-wrapper">
    <div id="media-insert">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="lorem ipsum">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="media-description">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</main>
```

---

## Edit:

Here is how I want it to look like (but without setting the image as the background of the parent):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#examples {
  display: flex;
}

#examples > div {
  margin: 1em
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.media-description {
  /* the description must take the minimum possible space (flex-grow: 0) to fit everything (flex-shrink: 0) */
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.media-wrapper {
  /* the wrapper should shrink/grow to fit the remaining space */
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.media-wrapper .media-insert {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

#img-example-1 {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/200/300");
}

#img-example-2 {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/100/100");
}


/***** debug *****/

main {
  border: 5px solid red;
  /* simulate phone screen */
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
}

.media-wrapper {
  border: 5px solid green;
}

.media-insert {
  border: 5px solid lightgreen;
}


.media-description {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="examples">

  <div>
    <p>
      Image too big<br>
      -> scale down
    </p>
    <main>
      <div class="media-wrapper">
        <div class="media-insert" id="img-example-1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="media-description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>
      Image smaller than parent<br>
      -> image keeps its size
    </p>
    <main>
      <div class="media-wrapper">
        <div class="media-insert" id="img-example-2"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="media-description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a max px size for the image wrapper? Can it be max 400px wide or high for example? If so and you constrain this and use `overflow: hidden` on the parent then the images won't expand (but they will be cut off in one direction.

Comment: Or set `max-width: 200px; height: auto`. Or swap them, depending if you are serving more portrait images than landscape.

Comment: I don't want to cut the image and I serve all kind of aspect ratios and sizes.

Comment: Then you have to set a max width or height this will resize the images and it won't matter which orientation or if the image is 200px or 4000px in width or height.

Comment: This doesn't work when the parent element don't have a fixed size. This is what this question is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! I modified [passatgt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68880528/css-fit-an-image-into-an-unknown-size-parent/68881460#68881460) (thanks for showing me how `object-fit` works).

The modification I made:

- All the image is visible: `object-fit: contain` instead of `object-fit: cover`
- The image keeps its size if it already fits in the parent (`max-width` and `max-height` instead of `width` and `height`).
- Added an example to show that it works with image bigger than parent and smaller than parent.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#examples {
  display: flex;
}

#examples > div {
  margin: 1em
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.media-description {
  /* the description must take the minimum possible space (flex-grow: 0) to fit everything (flex-shrink: 0) */
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.media-wrapper {
  /* the wrapper should shrink/grow to fit the remaining space */
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.media-wrapper .media-insert {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.media-wrapper .media-insert img {
   position:absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: 100%;
   object-fit: contain;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/***** debug *****/

main {
  border: 5px solid red;
  /* simulate phone screen */
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
}

.media-wrapper {
  border: 5px solid green;
}

.media-insert {
  border: 5px solid lightgreen;
}


.media-description {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="examples">

  <div>
    <p>
      Image too big<br>
      -> scale down
    </p>
    <main>
      <div class="media-wrapper">
        <div class="media-insert">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="lorem ipsum">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="media-description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>
      Image smaller than parent<br>
      -> image keeps its size
    </p>
    <main>
      <div class="media-wrapper">
        <div class="media-insert">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="lorem ipsum">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="media-description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could position the image with absolute position, set it to 100% width and height and use the `object-fit` property to style it. It's like the `background-size: cover`:

```css
* {
     box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 main {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: space-between;
 }

 #media-description {
     /* the description must take the minimum possible space (flex-grow: 0) to fit everything (flex-shrink: 0) */
     flex-shrink: 0;
     flex-grow: 0;
 }

 #media-wrapper {
     /* the wrapper should shrink/grow to fit the remaining space */
     flex-shrink: 1;
     flex-grow: 1;
 }

 #media-wrapper #media-insert {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     /* center the image */
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
   background:red;
   position:relative;
 }

 #media-wrapper #media-insert img {
     position:absolute;
   left:0;
   top:0;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   object-fit:cover;
 }

 /***** debug *****/

 main {
     border: 5px solid red;
     /* simulate phone screen */
     width: 350px;
     height: 500px;
 }

 #media-wrapper {
     border: 5px solid green;
 }

 #media-insert {
     border: 5px solid lightgreen;
 }


 #media-description {
     border: 5px solid blue;
 }
```

```html
<main>
     <div id="media-wrapper">
         <div id="media-insert">
             <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="lorem ipsum">
         </div>
     </div>
     <div id="media-description">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
     </div>
 </main>
```

Comment: Thanks, with `object-fit: contain`, it's pretty close of want I want to achieve! But now, if an image is smaller than its parent, it will scale up. If it already fits in its parent, I don't want to modify its size.

Comment: Thanks for showing me how the `object-fit` works. I modified your answer to meet my needs and it works like a charm: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68882054/9515617

Answer (score 0):

change the `max-width` and `max-height` to `min`

```
#media-wrapper #media-insert img {
  display: block;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

Edit: or are you trying just to increase the width to fit the parent?

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear. I edited it to add an example of want I want to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to decrease the size of the image to fit in the parent. The parent should not change its size whether the image is present or not. Also, if the image already fits, the image size must not increase.